# Every Ubuntu update breaks rEFInd on my MBP

Tags: dual-boot, efi

Every time when I'm updating Ubuntu with:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
```

I've needed to do this in MBP recovery mode:

```
mkdir /Volumes/EFI
mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/EFI
bless --mount /Volumes/EFI --setBoot --file /Volumes/EFI/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi --shortform
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Avoid is quite broad. One might patch Ubuntu to not break, patch OS to automate the bless, not update, run Ubuntu in virtualization. Would you either show a little more research on what you think avoiding looks like or be clear what result you wish to change?

Comment: I suppose a certain amount of this is unavoidable because once you *authorize* an installer to install - it is authorized to do whatever it's programmed to do. That said, I've seen Apple upgrades stage a 'boot coup' , but I've never seen Ubuntu do it. Is this a dual-boot system? Did you install GRUB w/ Ubuntu?

Comment: @Seamus yes, GRUB installed with Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to trace what is happening... a *"boot debugger"* so to speak - maybe @DavidAnderson knows of one? Absent that, I'd tend to suspect GRUB - but that is likely due to the fact that I've never had much "luck" with it. However: if this were me, I think I would try to [remove GRUB](https://www.techonia.com/1063/remove-grub-bootloader-macbook-pro-air-imac), and re-install `rEFInd`.

Comment: @Seamus already thinked about this but I want to use GRUB to save Ubuntu recovery mode. What can I else do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

```
umount /boot/efi
```

I'm running this automatically at Ubuntu startup. When EFI partition needed with running Ubuntu I can mount it manually. Now I don't need to "rebless" rEFInd after every Ubuntu upgrade.